# PEAP WiFi authentication issues

Tags: wireless, wpa2

I've looked at similar posts on this topic but nothing so far is working.

Unfortunately I can connect to my Colleges Guest WIFI but not the actual WiFi. The school is running security: WPA & WPA2 Enterprise and PEAP authentication.

Some of the things I’ve tried is:

1. changing the config file inside `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`. My config file does not have

   ```
   system-ca-cert=true
   ```
2. Attaching the schools CA Certificate (From the IT Deparment)
3. Changing the user name schema to `Domain\Username`
4. Trying to install drivers (however that’s a rabbit hole inside a rabbit hole) etc.

Comment: Your IT department is the place to ask. They and only they can tell you what certs and other settings are needed. Before that, of course, you need to make sure the WiFi works is regular networks. If not this question is nonsensical because you need to tackle that problem before setting up the more complex WiFi network.

Comment: My IT Department turned me away saying that quote: "It has to be something wrong with that OS beacuse the certs we're giving you are correct".  ( Tbh I didnt really have high hopes beacuse I had to explain to them what linux was and why I needed the certs ). Also, the regular WIFI works like I mentioned  I can connect to the guest wifi and most any other wifi its specifically my schools network under PEAP authentication.

Comment: It's similar however most the answers are outdated as the post is from 4-5 years ago.

Comment: @knechtsr: Age alone doesn't make them outdated. Could you please [edit] your question to explain what *exactly* you did, what you wanted to achieve and what happened instead? Can you to connect to wireless networks with WPA2 personal authentication successfully? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Yes I can connect to WPA2 Personal authentication just not WPA2 Enterprise.